# How to calculate limit of sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let : $$a_n=\left(\frac{3n^2+7}{2n^2+4n}\right)^{3n}$$

I need to find : $$\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n$$

so I think that I need to make the sequence to something like $\left(1+\frac{a}{\:n}\right)^n$, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The base tends to $3/2>1$. What can you conclude now?

Comment: That path will mislead you. Instead, notice that the limit of the value in the brackets is 3/2.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3n^2+7}{2n^2+4n}=\frac{3+\frac{7}{n^2}}{2+\frac{4}{n}}\rightarrow\frac{3}{2}>1,$$
which says that the limit does not exist or we can say that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=+\infty$.

Maybe your teacher means the following reasoning.

By Bernoulli we obtain
$$a_n=\left(1+\frac{n^2-4n+7}{2n^2+4n}\right)^{3n}\geq1+\frac{3n(n^2-4n+7)}{2n^2+4n}\rightarrow+\infty.$$

Comment: the was my first thought but after i asked my teacher he give me a hint that the limit has something to do with $e$

Comment: @D.Z.O I don't think so. We can think here about $e$ if $\frac{3n^2+7}{2n^2+4n}\rightarrow1,$ but it's not so.

Comment: Why do you say "The limit does not exist" ? The limit exists, it is $+\infty$.

Comment: so  can i say that $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{n^2-4n+7}{n\left(2n+4\right)}\right)$ so  $b_n=\frac{n^2-4n+7}{\left(2n+4\right)}$ then $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(b_n\right) = \infty $ thats mean $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a_n\right) =\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{b_n}{n}\right)= e^\infty = \infty $ ?

Comment: @Jean Marie $+\infty$ it's not number. Take any book about calculus and read about limits. It wcould help you.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg While I agree $+\infty$ is not a number (except in the context of one-point compactification or the like), I think there is still some value in saying that a limit "is" $+\infty$. (I would prefer the term "approaches"). There is definitely a difference between a limit not existing because of an essential singularity or the like and a limit approaching $+\infty$. So I would say the OP isn't *entirely* wrong in saying the limit exists

Comment: @D.Z.O It should be $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{n^2-4n+7}{n(2n+4)}\right)=1,$ but it's not so. You can not use here $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{b_n}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{b_n}}=e$ because $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{b_n}{n}=0$ is wrong.

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg Please, don't use sarcastic comments like your last sentence.

Comment: what i did the i used that if $b_n \to x$ a sequence tends to $x$ then $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{b_n}{n}\right)^n=e^x$ (when $n  \to \infty$) so in this case $a_n=\left(\frac{3n^2+7}{2n^2+4n}\right)^{3n}=\left(\left(1+\frac{n^2-4n+7}{n\left(2n+4\right)}\right)^n\right)^3$ so we take $b_n=\frac{n^2-4n+7}{\left(2n+4\right)} \to \infty$ so we get $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a_n\right)=e^{\infty ^3}=\infty $

Comment: If $x$ the number then you can do it. If $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{b_n}{n}\neq0$ you can not do it by definition of $e$: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e.$ I think your reasoning with $e^{\infty^3}=\infty$ is total wrong.

Comment: oh okey , thanks alot

Comment: You are welcome!